# how to declare a static vector member

Tags: c++, static, extern

I've some problems to declare a static member of type `std::vector<std::string>`, in principle I can replace it with an array `std::string[]`.

I've a lot of troubles: if I declare it as `static` and then I initialize in the implementation (cpp file) it works but if I want to create a new class inheriting from the first in a second file it complains about

```
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘std::string []’
```

If I decalre it in the header I've problems with double declarations.

What's the proper way? Do I have to use extern? How?

I've:

file_A.h:

```
class A { public: static string s[]; }
```

file_A.cpp:

```
string A::s[] = { ... };
```

file_B.h

```
class B : public A
```

file_B.cpp

```
void B::function()
{
for (string* s = A::s; s != A::s + sizeof(A::s) / sizeof(string); ++s)
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` is not a function type. It's a class type.

Comment: how does it complain? is that really all what is in your file_B.h?

Comment: First one should work fine.  what error are you getting? What compiler?

Comment: If you'll use array, you need to specify its size in the declaration in the header: `class A { public: static string s[42]; }`

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what the `sizeof` operator is doing. It gives you the size of data *types*, not of the actual data. Sometimes, the size of the data type happens to be the same as the size of the actual data. This is only the case when the data type itself defines how much data can fit in it:

```
int a[50]; // 50 ints: sizeof(a) == 50 * sizeof(int)
```

Furthermore, `sizeof` can only operate on a complete type. This is not a complete type:

```
int a[];
```

An incomplete type is a type that lacks information needed to determine its size. You will never be able to use `sizeof` to get the size of `a` here.

Comment: why `string A::s[] = { ... };` is not complete?

Comment: `int a[50]; // sizeof(a) == 50`
Wrong --
`int a[50]; // sizeof(a) == sizeof(int)*50`
Right

Comment: @Ruu Oopsie... Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you're trying to sizeof of `string s[]`. Compiler nothing know about size of your string array.

For example:

```
void B::function()
{
for (string* s = A::s; s != A::s + sizeof(A::s) / sizeof(string); ++s)
}
```

In your function instead sizeof(). You can use `for (int i = 0; !A::s[i].empty(); ++i)` to get size of string array.

PS. If you don't use sizeof(string[]). Your code will be working.

Comment: You're correct about the problem, but your suggested "solution" will most likely just give a segmentation fault, unless wiso decides to always "mark" the end of the array by putting an empty string there.  (In particular, if every string in the array is non-empty, then you'll end up accessing memory past the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior)

Comment: @Edward Loper, I agree with you. But,virtually, I suggested pseudocode. And don't said use it. For example :)